# Django - get() returned more than one model_item -- it returned 2

Tags: python, django, model

I have this error:

```
get() returned more than one model_item -- it returned 2!
```

The line that throw this error is :

```
earray.sort(key=lambda x:"%s" % (x.model_rule.model_item.PRDT_ID.TITLE))
```

In below my model :

**model_rule**:

```
class model_rule(models.Model):
    key_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    model_item = models.ForeignKey(model_item,db_column='item_key_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s:%s" % (self.model_item.PRDT_ID.TITLE,self.rule.name)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'model_rule'
```

**model_item**:

```
class model_item(models.Model):
    ITEM_Id = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True, db_column = "item_id")
    Id = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True, db_column = "public_id")
    category_ID = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True, db_column="category_ID")
    PRDT_ID = models.ForeignKey('PRODUCT', db_column = "product_id")    

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'model_item'
```

There are many location where `x.model_rule.model_item` used I can't change one by one, so I need to do change one time in model by adding this filter in list of `category_ID` `(17,11,16,15,4,1)` to avoid this error and every time
`model_rule.model_item` or `model_rule.filter` called the filter is added to the query.

Comment: please post full error trace and also as the error said post the corresponding views code that has the `get` query.

Comment: without error trace what i need to do is in the question

Comment: in your question, you have added the line which gives you the error. But the variable in that line, there is no context given. i.e how you got `x`. So if you want people to help you. You need to give more context.

Comment: 1st of all in django get method only return one object . to get multiple objects use filter method

Comment: @Charlizard:if get method always return one object ,Where the error comes from!!, Theoretically is true but in reality it is possible.